# Display data from database on a separate html page

Tags: python, html, sql, cs50

I am not sure if this question has been answered before, I tried to find other answers, but was unsuccessful, it may be that I am not put the right searches.

I am trying to complete the CS50 Web Finance project, and I'm running into a wall with the very beginning of the portfolio page. More specifically, I'm having trouble extracting data from my finance.db on my python page and then displaying it on my portfolio.html page. I think that I have successfully extracted the username from my finance.db, as shown in the code below.

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""
     # look up the current user
    user = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = :id", id=session["user_id"])


    return render_template("portfolio.html")
```

But, no matter what I do in my portfolio.html I cannot get it so say "Hello [username]" is just keeps saying "Hello undefined"

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Home
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
  <p>Hello {{ [username] }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm sure this is something that most people are able to get, but I'm still kind of new and I just don't understand. I've tried to look up resources, but the only thing I've found is other people's code, and I don't want to copy and paste, I want to learn how to do it properly, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flask, you just need to 'pass' the username info to your portfolio.html page via `render_template`.

So, like:

```
return render_template("portfolio.html", username=user)
```

Then display this in the template with:

```
  <p>Hello {{username}}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked...mostly, but now when I run flask it says "Hello [{'username': 'rb1294'}]" instead of justle "Hello rb1294" any idea how I can change that? Thanks again

Comment: It does the same thing displaying the same "Hello [{'username': 'rb1294'}]"